# Why is Parsec's uncons explicitly inlined for Text but not ByteString?

Tags: haskell, inline

[There's](https://github.com/aslatter/parsec/blob/master/Text/Parsec/Prim.hs#L372-L393) abstraction layer used by Parsec, type class `Stream`, it looks like this:

```
class (Monad m, ShowToken t) => Stream s m t | s -> t where
  uncons :: s -> m (Maybe (t, s))

instance (Monad m, ShowToken t) => Stream [t] m t where
  uncons []     = return Nothing
  uncons (t:ts) = return $ Just (t, ts)
  {-# INLINE uncons #-}

instance Monad m => Stream CL.ByteString m Char where
  uncons = return . CL.uncons

instance Monad m => Stream C.ByteString m Char where
  uncons = return . C.uncons

instance Monad m => Stream T.Text m Char where
  uncons = return . T.uncons
  {-# INLINE uncons #-}

instance Monad m => Stream TL.Text m Char where
  uncons = return . TL.uncons
  {-# INLINE uncons #-}
```

I wonder if inlining is a good idea here, then why `uncons` in `ByteString`'s instance of `Stream` is not inlined?

Should all these functions be inlined or none of them, or `Text` and `ByteString` are so different that we should inline one and shouldn't inline the other?

Comment: If I may take a stab, lists and `Text` are subject to fusion but `ByteString`-s are not.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, so does this mean that Parsec's performance for `ByteString` is *very* poor and inlining those functions won't really change anything?

Comment: Fusion crucially relies on inlining, and missing it can sometimes make performance worse, hence the pragmas (I believe). Without pragmas GHC will still often inline the method. Also, the performance for ByteString isn't "very poor", I think it's the fastest for Parsec.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, OK, that means that things can be fast even without fusion. Feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no real reason. Probably no-one paid attention,
benchmarked and showed that there's benefit for or against `{-# INLINE #-}`.

When `Stream Text` instances was added in [a commit from 2011](https://github.com/aslatter/parsec/commit/b7fed21061000168a37df89b5a05cf09e7e13273)
it came with `{-# INLINE #-}` pragma.

On the other hand, `Stream ByteString` [was touched last time in Feb 2008](https://github.com/aslatter/parsec/commit/34ea8270c96883436232913721ce3903fe4d7cfc),
with the previous commit being *Initial import* from Jan 2008. It didn't have any `INLINE` pragmas

So if you think that there's a reason to have or not to have `{-# INLINE #-}` pragmas
on those instances, make benchmarks proving your case. I'm not aware there are
any. It might make sense to inline `<*>` and `>>=` too, of `ParsecT`.

Related: I recently added few inline pragmas to lucid, because benchmarks clearly
show they make difference; but OTOH you shouldn't sprinkle them to everything.